# Problem faced by Bayes when developing his method for Bayesian Inference

Tags: bayesian, inference

I am reading *Principles of Statistics* (MG Bulmer, 1965) and stumbled upon the problem that Bayes considered when developing his theorem. Bulmer makes use of $dP$ and I have no idea what it means. In his words:

> The problem that Bayes himself considered was the following. Suppose that some event has an unknown probability, $P$, of occurring and that in $n$ trials it has occurred $x$ times and failed to occur $n - x$ times. What is the probability that $P$ lies between two fixed values, $a$ and $b$? Bayes first notes that the probability of the event occurring $x$ times out of $n$ is
>
> $\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}P^x(1-P)^{n-x}$.
>
> This is the likelihood. He then remarks that if nothing was known about $P$ before the experiment was done it is reasonable to suppose that it was equally likely to lie in any equal interval; hence the probability that $P$ lay in a small interval of length $dP$ was initially $dP$ and so the joint probability that it lay in this interval and that the even occurs $x$ times out of $n$ is
>
> $\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}P^x(1-P)^{n-x}dP$.
>
> The posterior probability that $P$ lies between $a$ and $b$ is thus proportional to the integral of this expression from $a$ to $b$ and is equal to
>
> $\frac{\int_a^b P^x(1-P)^{n-x}dP}{\int_0^1 P^x(1-P)^{n-x}dP}$.

I believe this last ratio comes directly from the conditional probability formula and I understand where the likelihood comes from. I do not understand the argument regarding $dP$ however.

What is $dP$? Does the author mean $dP = d \times P$ or is $dP$ some infinitesimally small interval that has nothing to do with the parameter $P$?

In case it's some super small interval, how come the joint probability is $P(X=x) \times dP$?

Comment: Yes, $dP$ is the length of some infinitesimally small interval, for example $[0.1, 0.1001]$. Note that $P(X=x)$ depends on $P$, so it's really $P(X=x|P)$. So the joint probability that $P$ lies in $[0.1, 0.1001]$ *and* $X=x$ is approximately $P(X=x|P=0.1) \times 0.0001$.

Comment: The modern notation $\text dP$ is the same as $\text dx$, it denotes the dominating (Lebesgue) measure when computing the integral. It does not appear in the Essay.